# Replace for loops that exchange attributes of objects with numpy function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, attributes, nested-loops

I made a bouncing ball simulation in Matplotlib, the update function exchange the move vectors (attributes) of the balls when they collide. Is it possible to replace the for loops in the update function with a Numpy function or other way to increase the FPS?

```
def update(self):
    for i in range(len(balls)):
        ball = balls[i]
        for j in range(len(balls)):
            other_ball = balls[j]
            if ball != other_ball:
                distance = ((other_ball.xy[0] - ball.xy[0]) ** 2 + (other_ball.xy[1] - ball.xy[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5
                if distance < 15:
                    # exchange move vectors
                    temp_vx = ball.v[0]
                    temp_vy = ball.v[1]
                    ball.v[0] = other_ball.v[0]
                    ball.v[1] = other_ball.v[1]
                    other_ball.v[0] = temp_vx
                    other_ball.v[1] = temp_vy
```

Comment: no, but you can remove the square root (`**0.5`) and just compare the squared distance to `15**2`. You still need to compute pairwise distances, but maybe you can do some tricks, like not recomputing distances for pairs that haven;t moved. Of course you can parallelize this distances by giving the task to a GPU if you want to increase FPS.

Answer (score 1):

You can store all balls' positions in a single `np.array` of `shape` `len(balls)`x`2`, and similarly holds their velocities in another such array.
You update will then look like:

```py
from scipy.spatial import distance

def update(balls_xy : np.array, balls_v : np.array):
  dist = distance.cdist(balls_xy, balls_xy)
  i, j = np.argwhere(dist < 15)
  # only one representative per colliding pair
  sel = i < j
  i = i[sel]
  j = j[sel]
  # switch the directions
  balls_v[i, :], balls_v[j, :] = balls_v[j, :], balls_v[i, :]
  return balls_v
```

see [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) for more details.